# What is the use of using address in quote object while calculating total of cart(table: sales_flat_quote_address)

Tags: cart, quote, addtocart, totals

Please explain why magento involve **address** while calculating grand total and other calculations while calling collectTotals() in saving cart.It involve table **sales_flat_quote_address** while interacting with **sales_flat_quote**

Answer (score 1):

The shipping address is used to determine the cost of the shipping method, because it might be a different cost for the shipping whether you ship to USA, Germany or Denmark.

If a shipping method is already set in the session that is.

For example if you go into the checkout and select a shipping method and then go back to the cart, then your shipping costs will be shown on the cart page.

Comment: What if I need to add an attribute like tax in my case(advance partial payment) which is independent of shipping address?Do I need to add that attribute to **sales_flat_quote_address**